# conversion from "glm::detail::tmat4x4<glm::lowp_float>" to "glm::mat4"

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have been following [this](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Rendering-Sprites) tutorial creating 2d games with opengl. I have a problem creating an orthogonal projection matrix. I used glm::ortho() as stated in the [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Rendering-Sprites). But I have this problem

***no suitable user-defined conversion from "glm::detail::tmat4x4glm::lowp_float" to "glm::mat4" exists***.
How can I fix this problem?

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<float>(this->Width), 
    static_cast<float>(this->Height), 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Maybe, there is something required that your compiler doesn't support? Please, provide a bit more context. (Please, don't expect that the reader has to follow your links to understand your issue.)